# Archive templates based on taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archive-template

I have a custom post type, service-provider, with two taxonomies, area and service.
I wanted to make a template based on the taxonomies.

```
function template_taxonomy($template) {
    if (is_archive()) {
        if ((is_tax('service') and is_tax('area')) or is_tax('service')) {
            $template = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy_service.php' ) );
        } else if (is_tax('area') and !(is_tax('service'))) {
            $template = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy_area.php' ) );
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

The code is pretty simple but my problem is, when I try to visit this URL

> http://www.site.com/?service-provider&service=electricians&area=north-shore-lower

the service taxonomy doesn't seem to exist, so it uses the taxonomy_area.php template. Also tried just using the taxonomy_service.php template and it seems like the area taxonomy doesn't exist on that template either.

Any ideas?

Comment: That template is going to be used to display the taxonomy archive or a post? When and where do you call the function in the code you have posted? Also, the URL you have posted is wrong, notice that the `service-provider` query string has no value.

Comment: Also, take a look to [template_inlude entry in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include), you can create a template file for each taxonomy, with the name `taxonomy-$taxonomy-slug.php`, and Wordpress will load it automatially.

Comment: I do use template_include. It's in functions.php of a child theme. I need to to display it in the archives.

Comment: And I'm not sure about the URL being wrong. It displays what I want to display, just using the wrong template.

Comment: If the URL is giving you what you want maybe you don't need to have `service-provider` in the URL because that query string has no value in the URL you posted. Anyway, I ask you again: What do you want in that page? A list of post of "service-provider" type that belongs to service=electricians & area=north-shore-lower? A single post? Anything else?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be listed in the archives but they need to be using different templates based on the conditions above.

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the time to help me out. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to display a list of post that belongs to two or more taxonomy terms, you are using the wrong URL. If your are usgin pretty permalinks, it should be:

```
 www.example.com/service-provider/?service=electricians&area=north-shore-lower
```

If you are not using pretty permalinks, it should be:

```
 www.example.com/?post-type=service-provider&service=electricians&area=north-shore-lower
```

Anyway, you are expected to be in multitax archive page and you can't check it with `is_tax()`, a function intended to check for single taxonomy archive. You can use some alternatives, like checking the actual $wp_query object:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'wpse_multietax_template');
function wpse_multietax_template( $template ){

    global $wp_query;

    if( (isset($wp_query->query_vars['service']) && isset($wp_query->query_vars['area'])) || isset($wp_query->query_vars['service']) ) {
         $template = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy_service.php' ) );
    } else if ( isset($wp_query->query_vars['area']) && !isset($wp_query->query_vars['service']) ) {
         $template = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy_area.php' ) );
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: I tried both URL's because I'm desperate. The first URL gave me a 404 error. The second one still uses the template for the area taxonomy.

Comment: Please, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works now but I have another problem. So in the template taxonomy_service.php I want to access the terms of each of the taxonomies. I tried using get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), 'service'); but that only seems to work on one taxonomy, namely area, just like my recent problem.

Comment: Thats another question. Anyway, `get_query_var('term')` will try to get the queried term within a taxonomy called "term" but you haven't queried for post in a taxonomy called "term", isn't it? You must use `get_query_var('service')`, `get_query_var('area')` or whatever taxonomy name you have queried. See [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) and [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) docs for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I got it working now. :D

Comment: You are wellcome. I'm glad to help.